# Criar um novo template a cada N elementos do *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-6

Olá, tenho um array `items:any[]` e quero iterar na view com o `*ngfor`, porém, estou utilizando uma template `<carousel>` onde para cada item desse slide eu chamo `<carousel-item>`, hoje meu código segue esta hierarquia:

```
<carousel>
  <carousel-item>
    <div *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{item.nome}}
    </div>
  </carousel-item>
  <carousel-item>
    <!-- outro conteúdo -->
  </carousel-item>
</carousel>
```

Com esse código eu tenho o seguinte resultado, note que o item 5 acaba excedendo o div:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida: eu quero que, a cada 4 elementos do *items* ele crie um novo template `<carousel-item>`, de forma a ficar dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se tem como resolver meu problema utilizando apenas a iteração do *ngFor e algum *ngIf ou modificando algo na hierarquia, mas não tenho ideia de como resolver sem prejudicar o desempenho da aplicação.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Tive um problema semelhante porém só consegui chamando uma função no `ngFor` que retorna um array de arrays, sendo os sub arrays com no máximo 4 itens, dai usei dois loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que dividir transformar seu array de items para uma matrix
Exemplo:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
```

deverá virar

```
[ ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e'] ];
```

Depois de transformar seu array em matriz, você pode adicionar um ngFor no seu carousel-item, exemplo:

```
// seu-component.ts
chunkItems: any = [];

ngOnInit() {
    this.chunkItems();
}

/** Transforma seu array de items em chunks **/
chunkItems() {
    this.chunkItems = [];
    const numberOfItemsPerRow = 4;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i += numberOfItemsPerRow) {
        this.chunkItems.push(this.items.slice(i, i + numberOfItemsPerRow));
    }
}

// seu-component.html
<carousel>
  <carousel-item *ngFor="let chunkItem of chunkItems">
    <div *ngFor="let item of chunkItem">
      {{item.nome}}
    </div>
  </carousel-item>
</carousel>
```

Comment: Perfeito, você acaba de salvar um dia